# Is it possible to copy row (with data, merging, style) in Excel using Epplus?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

The problem is that I need to insert data into Excel from the collection several times using a single template for the entire collection.

```
using (var pckg = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(association.TemplatePath)))
{
    var workSheet = pckg.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    var dataTable = WorksheetToDataTable(workSheet);
    /*Some stuff*/
    FindAndReplaceValue(workSheet, dictionary, row);
}

private DataTable WorksheetToDataTable(ExcelWorksheet oSheet)
{
    int totalRows = oSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
    int totalCols = oSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(oSheet.Name);
    DataRow dr = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++)
    {
        if (i > 1) dr = dt.Rows.Add();
        for (int j = 1; j <= totalCols; j++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
                dt.Columns.Add((oSheet.Cells[i, j].Value ?? "").ToString());
            else
                dr[j - 1] = (oSheet.Cells[i, j].Value ?? "").ToString();
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

First picture - My template. Second - First element of collection (with data, style, merging). Third - Other elements has only data

[image: This is my template]
[image: First element of collection has data, style, merging]
[image: Other elements got nothing besides data]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I just made copies of rows

```
    for (int i = 0; i < invoiceList.Count; i++)
    {
        workSheet.Cells[1, 1, totalRows, totalCols].Copy(workSheet.Cells[i * totalRows + 1, 1]);
    }
```

If you want to copy range just use :

```
workSheet.Cells["A1:I1"].Copy(workSheet.Cells["A4:I4"]);
```

Comment: How can i also copy the cell style, backgroundcolor/border etc of the whole range? Thanks

Comment: @kassi, You can copy cell with style etc. using solution listed above. If you want to copy range just use `workSheet.Cells["A1:I1"].Copy(workSheet.Cells["A4:I4"]);` Result: http://imgur.com/Ow4UUv5