# EPPlus copy a column's data into an empty column

Tags: c#, epplus

I need to swap two columns in an Excel document using EPPlus.
Or alternatively is there a way to copy a column into a freshly inserted column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30602767/4645236) to another question.

```
> workSheet.Cells["A1:I1"].Copy(workSheet.Cells["A4:I4"]);
```

but in order to copy say column 5 to column 2 you could do

```
> workSheet.Cells[1,5,100,5].Copy(workSheet.Cells[1,2,100,2]);
```

Instead of 100 you can plug in a maxvalue from one of your columns

```
var max = worksheet.Column(index).ColumnMax
```

Which allows you to have a less arbitrary

```
> workSheet.Cells[1,5,max,5].Copy(workSheet.Cells[1,2,max,2]);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't do a column range like `A:A`?

Comment: @CaptainPrinny you're always welcome to add an answer if you think there is a better way. I no longer use this library so I can't really speak to what I was thinking 3 years ago but the answer worked for me at the time.